# How to add a horizontal line at the top of my wordpress site

Tags: html, wordpress-theming

I want to have a top border on my wordpress site like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply this to the top of the whole page, apply styling to the body element in your CSS file:

```
body {border-top: 10px solid #93bfcc;}
```